# Having trouble sending form's info to email (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm making a webpage that's supposed to have a form that, when filled, is supposed to send all the info to a an email. However, I can't seem to make it work, and it's driving me crazy. I'm a beginner, so I was wondering if someone could please help me?

PHP and I aren't the bestest of friends... despite that, I haven't given up. It seems I've managed to connect index.php with contact-form-php, however, whenever I try it out, it's unable to capture the info typed into the form and instead sends me the **"else"** action, which is just a message saying there was an error. I really don't know how to solve it.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-align mx-5 ml-md-0" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
     <input class="form-control my-3 inputname" type="text" 
     placeholder="Name" id="dname">
     <input class="form-control my-3 inputemail" type="email" 
     placeholder="Email" id="demail">
     <textarea class="form-control my-3 inputtext" type="text" 
     placeholder="We're all ears..." rows="5" id="dtext"></textarea>
     <a href="https://vivasox.com/"><button type="submit" 
     class="btnsend">SEND</button></a>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   /* Capturing variables */
   $demail=   ( empty($_POST["demail"])   )  ?  NULL : $_POST["demail"];
   $dname=    ( empty($_POST["dname"])    )  ?  NULL : $_POST["dname"];
   $dtext= ( empty($_POST["dtext"]) )  ?  NULL : $_POST["dtext"];

   /* Verifying POST */
   if ($demail && $dname && $dtext){
       $for = 'myemail@hotmail.com';
       $mailheader = "From: ".$demail."\r\n";
       $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

       $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$dname."\n";
       $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$demail."\n";
       $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".nl2br($dtext)."\n";

       mail($for, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("Sorry. There seems to be a problem. Please try sending your message again!");
       header("Location: https://socklesslooksolution.com/");

   }else{
        /* Error message */
        echo "Error: Please fill the form!";
  }
?>
```

I expect it to send the email and then go back to the main page in the site, but it does neither of those things.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Your input and textarea are missing the name attribute, and why you are wrapping the submit with a `<a>` tag?

Comment: You must declare a name for your inputs. You're just declaring the Id. Try add to your input email `name='demail'` and do the same to the others inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inputs and textarea are missing the `name` attribute, you need that to send value when the form is submitted:

```
<form class="form-align mx-5 ml-md-0" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
     <input class="form-control my-3 inputname" type="text" name="dname" placeholder="Name" id="dname">
     <input class="form-control my-3 inputemail" type="email" name="demail" placeholder="Email" id="demail">
     <textarea class="form-control my-3 inputtext" type="text" name="dtext" placeholder="We're all ears..." rows="5" id="dtext"></textarea>
     <a href="https://vivasox.com/"><button type="submit" class="btnsend">SEND</button></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was it! I changed it and everything is working now :'D